# Firebase Crashlytics reporting fake crash on Android project with Retrofit and coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, crashlytics, coroutine

Crashlytics is reporting a crash in my project when a certain network request is returning a 400. I have been able to replicate this issue and the app is displaying the error popup as expected but it is not crashing. I am pretty confident that the app is not crashing at the indicated rate in Crashlytics, however, I am concerned about these numbers and I would like them to be accurate.

On top of that, Crashlytics shows that this crash is happening in very old versions of the app, when it wasn't happening (before kotlin or coroutines were added to the project).

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
   at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse + 49(KotlinExtensions.java:49)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse + 129(OkHttpCall.java:129)
   at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute + 174(RealCall.java:174)
   at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run + 32(NamedRunnable.java:32)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1113(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 588(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 818(Thread.java:818)
```

Has anyone experienced an issue like this or may have a clue of what's going on here?

Comment: Same problem here, we started having these, but the application actually does not crash. We handle the exceptions received from our REST API and display the error on the screen, where the user can continue to use the app as normal. Yet the reporting says it is a fatal crash :(

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I've found the problem. I had a request like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val response1 = api.request1()
        launch {
            val response2 = api.request2()
            ...
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error", e)
    }
}
```

I didn't have a `try catch` block inside the second coroutine. And because it's a different coroutine, the exception won't be caught by the parent, so you need to catch the exception there as well.

**Old answer:**

I'm having the same problem. It started after rewriting all requests from Rx to Coroutines. Reports are showing in both Play Console and Crashlytics with different exceptions.

Here is example of my code:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesApi(client: OkHttpClient, gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Api {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://url")
            .client(client.newBuilder().addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Header1", ...)
                        .addHeader("Header2", ...)
                        .build()
                chain.proceed(request)   
            }.build())
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .build()
            .create(Api::class.java)
}

viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val response = api.request()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error", e)
    }
}
```

Reports show that it crashes on `chain.proceed(request)`. But when i try to reproduce it by setting a 1 second timeout or even manually throwing an exception inside the interceptor all exceptions are getting caught inside the try block and it doesn't crash at all. Example exceptions:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException (Http2Stream.java:4)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut (Http2Stream.java:8)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders (Http2Stream.java:24)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.openResponseBody (Http2Codec.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept (CallServerInterceptor.java:27)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:4)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:69)
  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:69)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:27)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:27)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:70)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.a (RealInterceptorChain.java:6)
  at myproject.dagger.Module$providesApi$1.intercept (Module.java:4) <------------------ HERE
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.a (RealInterceptorChain.java:6)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:12)
  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:9)
  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:17)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Or

```
retrofit2.HttpException: 
  at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse (KotlinExtensions.java:2)
  at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse (OkHttpCall.java)
  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.a (RealCall.java)
  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Really frustrating as i'm getting thousands of reports everyday.

Answer (score -1):

Well Firebase will not report a **`Crash`** unless the application running on the end-user's device cause an **`ANR(Application Not Responding)`** error.

I would suggest to test the application on other physical devices if possible or multiple different android emulators with the version code that firebase reports are failing.

Comment: Fabric/Firebaser here - Crashlytics does not report ANRs.